# parse.com - how i can create query equal createdAt by date only with javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to find data by "createdAt" field but i need to search with date only (without time).

```
var d = new Date();
var query = new Parse.Query("TableName");
query.equalTo("createdAt", d);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you basically have to do to generate two dates:

- `date` at 0:0:0 time
- `date+1day` at 0:0:0 time

Then search for:

```
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', date);
query.lessThan('createdAt', datePlusOne);
```

This effectively gives you the range of dateT0:0:0 - dateT23:59:59.99999 inclusive, but in a safe way

If you want to use pure JavaScript:

```
// assuming date is the date/time to start from
 date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
// hours/min/sec/ms cleared
 var datePlusOne = new Date(date);
 datePlusOne.setDate(datePlusOne.getDate() + 1);
```

You can also use the [moment library](http://momentjs.com) to make your code easier to read/maintain. This library is also used server-side in parse.com, though it is an older version.

```
 m1 = new moment(date);
 m1.startOf('day');
 m2 = new moment(m1);
 m2.add(1, 'day');
// convert moment back to JavaScript dates
 date = m1.toDate();
 var datePlusOne = m2.toDate();
```

Full solution using moments:

```
var d = new Date();
var query = new Parse.Query("TableName");

var start = new moment(d);
start.startOf('day');
// from the start of the date (inclusive)
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', start.toDate());

var finish = new moment(start);
finish.add(1, 'day');
// till the start of tomorrow (non-inclusive)
query.lessThan('createdAt', finish.toDate());

query.find.then(function(results) {
  // use results
});
```

Comment: I see you tried to edit my answer. You do want to be inclusive (`greaterThanEqualTo`) on the first createdAt as you want to include 00:00:00 timed updated on the day, but exclusive for the next day (before 00:00:00 on the next day, but not including it).

Comment: "greaterThanEqualTo" not working, need to change it to "greaterThanOrEqualTo" https://parse.com/questions/javascript-query-using-greaterthan-createdat

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work until I realized that the line `start.startOf('day');` is never assigned to anything. I updated the initialization to `var start = new moment(d).startOf('day');` and it worked.  Likewise, `var finish = new moment(start).add(1, 'day');`

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for results, filtered by "created today", you could do this:

```
var moment = require("moment");
var start = moment().sod() //Start of day
var end = moment().eod() //End of day

var query = new Parse.Query("myClass")
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", start.format());
query.lessThan("createdAt", end.format());
query.find({...});
```

Of course, if you are looking for a greater timespan than "today", you would go with Timothy's answer.

This code has been tested in Parse Cloud Code with Momentjs 1.7.2

Comment: From moment 2.0.0 sod() change to startOf('day')