# compare createdAt field with date only (not datetime) on parse.com in android

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I am using parse.com in one of my app. I can insert/fetch data to/from parse. Everything works fine. But I want use createdAt field to fetch data.

I have two queries.

1. Fetch records which are created today.
2. Fetch records which are created before today.

Problem is parse compares createdAt fields using date-time so I can not use new Date() in query parameter. Is there any way to compare createdAt field by date only?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099051/parse-com-how-i-can-create-query-equal-createdat-by-date-only-with-javascript) question is similar to mine. But is there any standard method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, You need  function something like a keyword "like" which is used in Database to check if a substring exists in a column. So, we do have a method in Parse's Android APIs.

For that you need to call `whereContains(String key, String substring)` 
which will add a constraint for finding string values that contain a provided string.

So, you can write something like this:

`query.whereContains("createdAt", "25-05-2015");`

That'll only retrieve those data which fall on this date and won't include time.

**Doc Reference:**   https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/#ParseQuery/whereContains

**EDIT:**

As createdAt column is Date type, It'll accept a Date variable only. In that case above mentioned function won't work. So, achieving that we will have to use `whereGreaterThan` and `whereLessThan`. Sample code snippet is:

```
Date midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0);
midnight.setMinutes(0);
midnight.setSeconds(0);

Date elevenfiftynine = new Date();
elevenfiftynine.setHours(23);
elevenfiftynine.setMinutes(59);
elevenfiftynine.setSeconds(59);

query.whereGreaterThan(Constants.CREATED_AT_KEY, midnight);
query.whereLessThan(Constants.CREATED_AT_KEY, elevenfiftynine);
```

**Reference:** https://www.parse.com/questions/android-api-query-to-get-all-objects-created-today

Comment: What results do you get when you  use this method ? @KetanAhir

Comment: sry for delay.. `whereContains` does not work for date. It's for strings. I found a solution and will post here soon.

Comment: I figure out some way to do it. You might want to recheck my answer.

Comment: Exactly this is what I found and it works for me. Anyways thanks.