# Get the parsobject add today

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I am using parse sdk android. I want to get the parseobject add today or after a date.I have used a calender to get datetime and make query for 
Created date but it return null.

Comment: Date today = new Date();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
        query.whereLessThan("createdAd",  today.getTime());

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099051/parse-com-how-i-can-create-query-equal-createdat-by-date-only-with-javascript)

Comment: This for javasript sdk 
i have make a similaire solution for my problem but i still have a null result however i have data in my data base

Comment: may be its date format issue. for testing purpose. check it with static date. means copy date from parse database and put in  `whereLessThan`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is format date problem

Comment: How can we convert new Date() to format pase date "createdAt" ?